# javascript on form option to pass two values, one for hidden/visible functionality, the second for the data-value

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

I'm working with a form which displays the relevant next input box based on the selected value.

I have the code working using `value="0"` and adding up per row.

```
<option value="4">Chordata</option>
```

Unfortunately this passed the value `4` through the form rather than the text `Chordata`.

So far I've figured out how to pass a second value:

```
<option value="4" data-value="Chordata">Chordata</option>
```

Using an alert I can see the selected data.

```
$('#sel1_1').on('change', function() {
  alert('value is:' + $("#sel1_1 option:selected").data('value')
  )
});
```

In the code `var ch` is the selected `#id` of the `<select>` tag:

```
<select class="form-control" name='phylum' id="sel1_1" style="display:none;">
  <!-- Animalia -->
  <option value="0" data-value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1" data-value="Annelid">Annelid</option>
  <option value="2" data-value="Arthropod">Arthropod</option>
  <option value="3" data-value="Bryozoa">Bryozoa</option>
  <option value="4" data-value="Chordata">Chordata</option>
  <option value="5" data-value="Cnidaria">Cnidaria</option>
  <option value="6" data-value="Echinoderm">Echinoderm</option>
  <option value="7" data-value="Mollusc">Mollusc</option>
  <option value="8" data-value="Nematode">Nematode</option>
  <option value="9" data-value="Platyhelminthes">Platyhelminthes</option>
  <option value="10" data-value="Rotifer">Rotifer</option>
  <option value="11" data-value="Sponge">Sponge</option>
</select>
```

So when option 4 is chosen the alert appears, but how do I add the `$("#sel1_1 option:selected").data('value');` to the javascript? Below you'll see I've assigned `data` as the `data-value` but obviously that'll break the script. So I want to keep `var ch = $("#sel1_1").val();` for the select functionality, but I also need some way to pass the real value `data-value` through `var data`.

I could switch the `value` with the text but then I'd need the `value-data` to be the integer responsible for the reveal of the next dropdown box.

This is part of the currently working script:

```
$("#sel1_1").change(function() {
  var select_nums = 11;
  $('#sel2_0').css({'display':'block'});
  var ch = $("#sel1_1").val(); // original value
  // var data = $("#sel1_1 option:selected").data('value'); //new code
  if(ch==0){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==1){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==2){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==3){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==4){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==5){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==6){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==7){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==8){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==9){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==10){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }else if(ch==11){
    for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
      $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
  }
});
```

Comment: "the value `4` through the form". I don't see it. Without a name attribute, you must be using AJAX, so you can pass whatever, such as `SelectElement.options[SelectElement.selectedIndex].text`.

Comment: @StackSlave the value `4` is what is passed for that option, the 4th option. `var ch = $("#sel1_1").val();` is what collects that, currently that is used as the value in the form. By assigning a second value to the option `data-value="some text"` a d using `$("#sel1_1 option:selected").data('value');` I can access a second value, but how do I integrate it into the script supplied? How do I tell the form to use the `data-value` rather than the `value`?

Comment: ok, stupidly simple, use the `value`  as the value to be submitted use `$("#sel1_1 option:selected").data('value');` for the selection fuctionality.

Comment: Besides a few Boolean setters and getters *(like VideoElement.controls = true)* HTML attributes in JavaScript *(jQuery included)* are Strings. To cast a String to a Number in JavaScript you simply put `+` in front of the String, like `let ch = +$('#sel1_1').val();`. You could also use `parseInt($('#sel1_1').val())` or `parseFloat($('#sel1_1').val())`, the second being useful for floating point numbers.

Comment: If all of those "extra" values are a 1:1 match with the option's text, then you don't need an additional data attribute to begin with - read the `.text()` of the selected option then, instead of its `.val()`-ue.